# How to increase/decrease indenting when stepping in/out of methods?

Tags: c#, testing, logging, log4net, data-driven-tests

TL;DR - jump to last paragraph

**Background**

I'm performing some data driven testing and using the log file as one of the testing outputs. It works something like this-

- Read first file in folder

  - Process first line and convert to a test
  - Run Test

    - Perform Validation 1
    - ...
  - ...
- Read next file
- Etc.

My log file reflects this:

```
INFO - Start RunAllFilesInFolder  
INFO - File1:
INFO -      Some info
INFO -      Executing Test 1  
INFO -          Validation A result
INFO -          ...
INFO -      ...  
INFO - File2:  
...
```

At the moment I use/call Log 4 net like this-

```
static class LogHelper
{
    internal static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
            (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
}

// another file
using static Some.Namespace.LogHelper;
class SomeClass
{
     Log.Info($"\t\tExecuting {t.Number}-{t.Name}");
}
```

Where indent = "\t", "\t\t" or "\t\t\t" depending on the level the test is in.

---

Is there a way to refactor the call to LogHelper.Log so that it takes into account a static "indent" that can be increased/decreased as I step into the different test levels without explicitly specifying the indent in each call?

I.e. 
Be able to call where applicable something like

```
Log.Indent.Increase();
```

Or

```
Log.Indent.Decrease();
```

And replace the above call to log simply with -

```
Log.Info($"Executing {t.Number}-{t.Name}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [stack trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) length, by counting the number of new lines:

```
int someSensibleMinimum = 3; //something that works for you
int count = Environment.StackTrace.Count(a => a=='\n');
var indent = new string('\t', Math.Max(0, count - someSensibleMinimum));
```

Note that in Release it may behave differently:

> However, the StackTrace property might not report as many method calls as expected due to code transformations that occur during optimization.

Or, you could automagically calculate the length using this approach (pseudocode):

```
int count = Environment.StackTrace.Count(a => a=='\n');
Look for stack length in dictionary<int,string> (length to indent string)
If found use it.
If not found, find the largest entry in dictionary where key < count
add new entry to dictionary one tab char longer
```

In code:

```
public sealed class IndentTracker
{
    private readonly ThreadLocal<Dictionary<int, string>> _dictionaryLocal =
        new ThreadLocal<Dictionary<int, string>>(() => new Dictionary<int, string>());

    public string GetIndent()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = _dictionaryLocal.Value;

        int count = Environment.StackTrace.Count(a => a == '\n');

        if (!dictionary.Any())
        {
            string initialIndent = string.Empty;
            dictionary.Add(count, initialIndent);
            return initialIndent;
        }

        string indent;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(count, out indent))
            return indent;

        string last = dictionary.OrderByDescending(k => k.Key).First(k => k.Key < count).Value;
        string newIndent = last + '\t';
        dictionary.Add(count, newIndent);
        return newIndent;
    }
}
```

This works when log in increasing depth order. For example, it fails if you log at stack depth 10, then 5 (without previously logging at stack depth 5 then 10).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Unfortunately it may be overkill for my purposes at this stage... Could you try answering the specific question (last paragraph) using your IndentTracker class?

Comment: I've edited the question to be clearer regarding what exactly I am after

Comment: Sounds very simple now. Not sure where you are having difficulty implementing that yourself.

Comment: I haven't tested this but I imagine using Environment.StackTrace is pretty expensive in terms of computation. if you are doing hundreds of logs per second it could have a significant performance impact

Comment: @Andy it has linear time complexity, if you double the number of logs, it will take double the time. Is it more expensive than not indenting, of course! am I responsible for providing a micro-optimised solution, not at all!

Comment: @weston I understand that it has liner complexity but I'd always understood that generating a stack trace is quite expensive, so I thought I'd do a test. On my laptop (YMMV) the Environment.StackTrace.Count(...) call takes about 0.5 ms with a stack depth of 30. A log.Debug call (writing to local disk) also takes about 0.5 ms so it looks like adding this could double the time it takes to do logging. It might be significant but it's actually a lot less impact than I had thought.

Comment: @Andy Cool, thanks for checking. My thought on the matter is: if you're doing lots of logging during time-critical code, and you are relying on pretty indenting too, then you are already in trouble, this won't make things worse!