# Indent Log Entries (Log4Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, log4net

I'm working on a Web API which requires http requests to be logged to a text file. For Logging, I'm using **Log4Net**.

Coming straight to the point: How can we indent Log entries that are managed by Log4Net? When a Web API receives a request, there are other methods calls involved as well. i.e. from Method A() to Method B().

My current log file looks like the following screenshot:
[image]

Could we some how make our log more readable and display them in a manner such as this one:

- Datetime Method Name A()

  - Datetime Method Name B()

The most important thing that needs to be kept in mind is that the Method B() can be accessed by some other method C() as well which in that case looks like this:

- Datetime Method Name C()

  - Datetime Method Name B()

The only related (some how) links i could find are:

- [How to add indentation to multi-line log entry in log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927351/how-to-add-indentation-to-multi-line-log-entry-in-log4net)
- [How to increase/decrease indenting when stepping in/out of methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195744/how-to-increase-decrease-indenting-when-stepping-in-out-of-methods)

But unfortunately they do not answer my question.

Comment: Why doesn't the second link answer your question?  That looks like exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @Amy that link do not answer the part which is how to track the initial method call? It could be either from method A() or method C(), which one should we (not) indent?

Comment: It uses the length of the stack trace to estimate the indent level.  You don't have to track the initial call, because that call would be at the first level of the stack trace.

Comment: What if at the same time another request proceeds to the resources? Stack trace may not be reliable in that case. And besides, the answers says "However, the StackTrace property might not report as many method calls as expected due to code transformations that occur during optimization."

Comment: Stack traces aren't reliable in production. But since you are logging DEBUG messages shouldn't it work fine?

Comment: Not really, my prime focus is to log requests to Web API methods which (for sure) will end up in Production sooner or later. @fortyTwo